# Pandas groupby with Grouper speed

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to get the average `Number of Records` by day for each Hospital.

```
|Hospital|Date|Number of Records
0|Hospital B|2018-02-12 16:07:54.183|5
1|Hospital B|2018-02-12 16:07:54.200|5
2|Hospital B|2018-02-12 16:07:54.220|2
3|Hospital B|2018-02-12 16:07:54.240|2
4|Hospital B|2018-02-12 16:07:54.253|1
5|Hospital B|2018-02-19 14:04:03.927|4
6|Hospital A|2017-12-18 00:00:00|9
7|Hospital A|2017-12-26 00:00:00|6
8|Hospital A|2018-02-05 14:12:49.587000|7

#df1 = pd.read_clipboard(sep='|')
```

This would be simple with `df1.groupby(['Hospital','Date']).sum().reset_index().groupby('Hospital').mean()` but this is incorrect due to the timestamps messing with the calculation for Hospital A. The answer should be 9.5.

I can solve this by truncating the dates like so.

```
df1['Date'] = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date'])
df1['Date'] = df1['Date'].dt.date
df1.groupby(['Hospital', 'Date']).sum().reset_index().groupby('Hospital').mean()

Hospital A  7.333333
Hospital B  9.500000
```

I also tried to solve this with [Grouper](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Grouper.html) because I like not having to "truncate" my dates for later analysis and not creating extra columns to avoid this. To my surprise, Grouper took almost 2x as long.

```
df1.set_index('Date').groupby([pd.Grouper(freq='D'),'Hospital']).sum().\
                                dropna().groupby('Hospital').mean()

Hospital A  7.333333
Hospital B  9.500000
```

`100 loops, best of 3: 5.37 ms per loop`for the first way and `100 loops, best of 3: 10.7 ms per loop` for Grouper.

Have I used Grouper correctly here? Perhaps it is taking a long time because Grouper creates the days in between the dates in the index which I remove with `drop_na()`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can also just use the date value without overwriting the data you have:

```
day = pd.to_datetime(df1['Date']).dt.date
df1.groupby(['Hospital', day]).sum().reset_index().groupby('Hospital').mean()

Hospital A  7.333333
Hospital B  9.500000
```

I'm guessing that the performance problem with `Grouper` is what you mention, generating a large amount of rows only to discard them later. However, there is a necessary performance impact in parsing the dates with `to_datetime`. You can try avoiding the parsing and simply slicing the string:

```
day = df1['Date'].str.slice(0, 10)
df1.groupby(['Hospital', day]).sum().reset_index().groupby('Hospital').mean()

Hospital A  7.333333
Hospital B  9.500000
```

Seems slightly faster in my machine, although I don't know if that would still be the case with large datasets.

Comment: Interesting - I never knew you could use groupby with a Series like that. This speed is definitely better `100 loops, best of 3: 7.91 ms per loop`

Answer (score 2):

Something like

```
df.groupby(['Hospital', df.Date.str[:10]]).sum().mean(level=0)
Out[915]: 
                 Number of Records
Hospital                          
Hospital A  7.0           7.333333
Hospital B  7.5           9.500000
```